# Subtitles creator/editor

Tags: osx, closed-captions

I am looking for a Mac OSX tool (local or online, free or not) that I can use to add subtitles to a video. Requirements

- Character-per-lines counter (possibly with threshold limit warning)
- Character-per-seconds counter (possibly with threshold limit warning)
- Manual subtitle sync regulation through draggable edges
- Audio Waveform